# How to select elements from a python dictionary and put it in array using

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x

How can I select specific elements, arrays or objects from python dictionary? and turn it Into array of python dictionaries (separated by the 'drug') From this

```
{'entities': [{'confidence': 0.9997971402351069,
   'end': 7,
   'entity': 'Drug',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 0,
   'value': 'ACETATE'},
  {'confidence': 0.9999706904447406,
   'end': 13,
   'entity': 'strength',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 8,
   'value': '25 MG'},
  {'confidence': 0.9998453283892297,
   'end': 15,
   'entity': 'Dosage',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 14,
   'value': '4'},
  {'confidence': 0.9997755143972202,
   'end': 32,
   'entity': 'Form',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 16,
   'value': 'SOLUTE CONCENTRE'},
  {'confidence': 0.9977145988367829,
   'end': 57,
   'entity': 'Duration',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 50,
   'value': '7 jours'},
  {'confidence': 0.9372295171779627,
   'end': 64,
   'entity': 'Drug',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 58,
   'value': 'ACIDAC'},
  {'confidence': 0.9982578804309925,
   'end': 71,
   'entity': 'strength',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 65,
   'value': '300 MG'},
  {'confidence': 0.9999528533143575,
   'end': 73,
   'entity': 'Dosage',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 72,
   'value': '5'},
  {'confidence': 0.9999296591678211,
   'end': 89,
   'entity': 'Form',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 74,
   'value': 'COMPRIME ENROBE'},
  {'confidence': 0.9992446956485572,
   'end': 114,
   'entity': 'Duration',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 107,
   'value': '1 jours'},
  {'confidence': 0.9296845434758102,
   'end': 136,
   'entity': 'Drug',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 115,
   'value': 'ACIDE ALENDRONIQUE GT'},
  {'confidence': 0.9997948784340954,
   'end': 142,
   'entity': 'strength',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 137,
   'value': '70 MG'},
  {'confidence': 0.9999681362182076,
   'end': 144,
   'entity': 'Dosage',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 143,
   'value': '7'},
  {'confidence': 0.9999797650629707,
   'end': 163,
   'entity': 'Form',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 145,
   'value': 'COMPRIME PELLICULE'},
  {'confidence': 0.9999587657131175,
   'end': 188,
   'entity': 'Duration',
   'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
   'start': 181,
   'value': '8 jours'}]}
```

to this

```
[{'confidence': 0.9997971402351069,
  'end': 0,
  'entity': 'Drug',
  'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
  'start': 7,
  'value': 'ACETATE'
  'relations': [{'confidence': 0.9997971402351069,
    'end': 13,
    'entity': 'strength',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 8,
    'value': '25 MG'},
   {'confidence': 0.9998453283892297,
    'end': 15,
    'entity': 'Dosage',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 14,
    'value': '4'},
   {'confidence': 0.9997755143972202,
    'end': 32,
    'entity': 'Form',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 16,
    'value': 'SOLUTE CONCENTRE'},
   {'confidence': 0.9977145988367829,
    'end': 57,
    'entity': 'Duration',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 50,
    'value': '7 jours'}]
},
{'confidence': 0.9372295171779627,
  'end': 58,
  'entity': 'Drug',
  'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
  'start': 54,
  'value': 'ACIDAC'
  'relations': [{'confidence': 0.9982578804309925,
    'end': 71,
    'entity': 'strength',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 65,
    'value': '300 MG'},
   {'confidence': 0.9999528533143575,
    'end': 73,
    'entity': 'Dosage',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 73,
    'value': '5'},
   {'confidence': 0.9999296591678211,
    'end': 89,
    'entity': 'Form',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 74,
    'value': 'COMPRIME ENROBE'},
   {'confidence': 0.9992446956485572,
    'end': 114,
    'entity': 'Duration',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 107,
    'value': '1 jours'}],
},
{'confidence': 0.9296845434758102,
  'end': 136,
  'entity': 'Drug',
  'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
  'start': 115,
  'value': 'ACIDE ALENDRONIQUE GT'
  'relations': [{'confidence': 0.9997948784340954,
    'end': 137,
    'entity': 'strength',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 142,
    'value': '70 MG'},
   {'confidence': 0.9999681362182076,
    'end': 143,
    'entity': 'Dosage',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 144,
    'value': '7'},
   {'confidence': 0.9999797650629707,
    'end': 145,
    'entity': 'Form',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 163,
    'value': 'COMPRIME PELLICULE'},
   {'confidence': 0.9999587657131175,
    'end': 188,
    'entity': 'Duration',
    'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor',
    'start': 188,
    'value': '8 jours'}],
}
]
```

I've found a way to convert this python dictionary into an array but it has only for one 'drug'

data = {'entities': [{'confidence': 0.9995591084943068, 'end': 21, 'entity': 'Drug', 'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor', 'start': 0, 'value': 'ACIDE ALENDRONIQUE GT'}, {'confidence': 0.9999265646779927, 'end': 27, 'entity': 'strength', 'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor', 'start': 22, 'value': '70 MG'}, {'confidence': 0.9999681660486393, 'end': 29, 'entity': 'Dosage', 'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor', 'start': 28, 'value': '7'}, {'confidence': 0.9999797654756072, 'end': 48, 'entity': 'Form', 'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor', 'start': 30, 'value': 'COMPRIME PELLICULE'}, {'confidence': 0.9999587657131175, 'end': 73, 'entity': 'Duration', 'extractor': 'CRFEntityExtractor', 'start': 66, 'value': '8 jours'}]}

```
from enum import Enum
class MEDICAL_ENTITY(str, Enum):
    DRUG = 'Drug'
    STRENGTH = 'Strength'
    DURATION = 'Duration'
    ROUTE = 'Route'
    FORM = 'Form'
    ADE = 'ADE'
    DOSAGE = 'Dosage'
    REASON = 'Reason'
    FREAQUENCY = 'Frequency'
```

```
def mapRasaEntityToMedicalEntity(data):
    entity = {}
    entities = []
    for item in payload['entities']:
        if item['entity'] == MEDICAL_ENTITY.DRUG:
            entity = item
        else:
            entities.append(item)
    entity['relations'] = entities
    result = []
    result.append(entity)
    return result
```

Comment: Didn't you ask a similar question earlier today?

Comment: As I told you in the earlier question, that's not JSON, JSON uses double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: I really don't know how to call it that's why i've called it Json

Comment: It's a Python dictionary.

Comment: Ok thak you Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the previous entity to the list whenever you start a new entity.

And entities that aren't `Drug` need to be appended to the `relations` list.

```
def mapRasaEntityToMedicalEntity(data):
    result = []
    entity = None
    for item in data['entities']:
        if item['entity'] == MEDICAL_ENTITY.DRUG:
            if entity:
                result.append(entity) # Push previous entity onto list
            entity = item
            entity['relations'] = []
        else:
            entity['relations'].append(item)
    result.append(entity) # Push the last entity
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
import json

my_json ="""{
  "Actors": [
    {
      "name": "Tom Cruise",
      "age": 56,
      "Born At": "Syracuse, NY",
      "Birthdate": "July 3, 1962",
      "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Robert Downey Jr.",
      "age": 53,
      "Born At": "New York City, NY",
      "Birthdate": "April 4, 1965",
      "photo": "https://jsonformatter.org/img/Robert-Downey-Jr.jpg"
    }
  ]
}"""


your_data = json.loads(my_json)

for i in your_data["Actors"]:
    print(i)
```

Output:

{'name': 'Tom Cruise', 'age': 56, 'Born At': 'Syracuse, NY', 'Birthdate': 'July 3, 1962', 'photo': 'https://jsonformatter.org/img/tom-cruise.jpg'}

{'name': 'Robert Downey Jr.', 'age': 53, 'Born At': 'New York City, NY', 'Birthdate': 'April 4, 1965', 'photo': 'https://jsonformatter.org/img/Robert-Downey-Jr.jpg'}